# Hide data-react-props in the HTML

Tags: reactjs

When using reactJS, I had to send the props to component which may contain sensitive user data. When I viewed the HTML, I found all the contents of the user object in the HTML as follows:

```
<div data-react-class="Admins" data-react-props="{"data":[{"id":16,"email":"tech@bluesapling.com","created_at":"2016-03-14T06:18:25.980Z","updated_at":"2016-03-21T04:41:28.865Z"},{"id":43,"email":"tech@bluesapling.comqweeee","created_at":"2016-03-19T07:38:56.638Z","updated_at":"2016-03-19T07:38:56.638Z"},{"id":44,"email":"tech@bluesapling.com111111","created_at":"2016-03-19T08:13:36.715Z","updated_at":"2016-03-19T08:13:36.715Z"},{"id":30,"email":"tech@bluesapling.com222","created_at":"2016-03-18T14:42:37.956Z","updated_at":"2016-03-18T14:42:37.956Z"},{"id":39,"email":"tech@bluesapling.com232","created_at":"2016-03-19T07:36:46.532Z","updated_at":"2016-03-19T07:36:46.532Z"}]}"><div class="admins" data-reactid=".0"><form id="admin-form" class="form-inline collapse " data-reactid=".0.1">
.........
</div>
```

Is there any way to hide the data which I need for the React component, but don't wish to be available directly in the HTML as-is.

Comment: cant you set it in the state instead of the props?

Comment: No, I can't set it in state

Comment: Well then return only crucial information from your server.   Like stuff that will be shown on the page anyways.  It looks like youre only having id, and email anyways.  Not really much 'sensitive' data. I mean, you were probably gonna display the email somewhere anyways, so wether its in a prop or on the page, its "stealable" from a hackers perspective anyways.  Even if its "invisible" its stealable.  From the javascript window object.  So I wouldn't worry to much about it.  Unless youre dealing with like credit cards or stuff like that

Comment: I didn't mean about this particular case though, I meant more in general. I have just started working on my project, soon it will be flooded with a lot of data. So, I was wondering if there is any way to hide it from being shown in the HTML, or I just have to live with it and handle it manually

Comment: Yeah, thats the norm.  Most data passed in props, usually gets displayed somewhere anyway.  So its usually data that will be available.  But yeah, in terms of hidden stuff.  No matter how you hide it.  It exists in the Javascript window object.  So any saavy person, knows where to go to get it.

Comment: @KyleK how do I set it in the state instead of props? state us built using props only..